# Open neighborhood of $T$-valued point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $T$ be another scheme. A $T$-valued point is a morphism from $T$ to $X$.

In this situation, some authors have described an "open neighborhood" of a $T$-valued point in $X$, but I haven't found a precise definition of this. I'd be grateful if someone can tell me one.

My guess would be: an open subscheme $U \subseteq X$ and morphism from $T$ to $U$ that, if we combine with the open immersion $U \rightarrow X$, gives the original point $T \rightarrow X$. I would like to confirm this?